# C# convert a for loop to for each (arraylist)

Tags: c#

I have a for loop that works but I need to implement a foreach loop. How do I change to a foreach loop ?

Here is the existing working for loop in a method

```
public void liststudents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < studentarraylist.Count; i++)
    {
        // Cast the object from the ArrayList to Student
        Student currentStudent = (Student)studentarraylist[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", currentStudent.FirstName, currentStudent.LastName);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I need to  cast the returned object from the ArrayList to a Student object like the above.

Comment: Before converting your `for` loop to `foreach`, Convert `ArrayList` to `List<Student>`, don't use `ArrayList` in 2015.

Comment: hey i know for loop is better BUT i need to implement a foreach loop.  its academic... I checked https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx but couldnt get it to work

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard. Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried foreach (int element in studentarraylist)
        {
           
   Student currentStudent = (Student)studentarraylist[i];
            System.Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}",currentStudent.FirstName, currentStudent.LastName);
        }

Comment: Add the code you tried to your question.

Comment: `foreach (int element in studentarraylist) ` ask yourself a question. Is your array list filled with `int`? or with something else?

Comment: WAIT.. I need to ensure the above code  cast the returned object from the ArrayList to a Student object

Comment: arraylist is full of objects (student).. only use the int to go through all items in arraylist.... i wanted to cast returned object to orignal type and print out each item in the arraylist

Comment: You can do the cast by declaring the type in your condition, like: `foreach (Student student in studentArrayList) Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);`

Comment: And @Habib point about using `List<T>` instead cannot be emphasized enough. There is literally no reason to use `ArrayList` unless you are using pre-generics .NET

Comment: sorry about the level I am at but this is an academic test... so thats why Im using arraylist.  Also I need to cast the object from the ArrayList to Student  object.. i cant just skip through a foreach

Comment: @Aindriu Are you using an IDE to compile these for you? The foreach already does the cast for you. If you're really deadset on a redundant cast, then I guess you can explicitly cast it inside the foreach loop and access the resulting redundancy in your Console.WriteLine.

Comment: `Also I need to cast the object from the ArrayList to Student object.` You keep saying that, but nobody knows what you mean by it. @Josh L. answer below does convert the objects in your `ArrayList` to `Student`, so what are you missing here?

Comment: @Matt - got the casting covered so I'm happy.

Comment: @Josh Yes I using VS2013, i know you can get by without doing the cast but I got var studentCast = someObject as Student; in the answer below and it does the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted, if all the objects are of type `Student`, then you can just use the `for` loop without a cast, and you should use a `List` (or anything other than `ArrayList`) instead.

If for some reason you are storing objects of types other than `Student` in your `studentsArrayList`, then you can get just the `Student` types by doing something like:

```
foreach (var someObject in studentsArrayList)
{
    // Try to cast the object as a Student
    var studentCast = someObject as Student;

    // If it's not null, the cast succeeded
    if (studentCast != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", studentCast.FirstName, studentCast.LastName);
    }
}
```

Or using Linq:

```
foreach (Student student in studentsArrayList.ToArray()
    .Where(s => s.GetType() == typeof (Student)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch.  +1 for the use of Linq.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for - I wanted to ensure that it at least tried to cast the object (its academic question) and uses a foreach loop so thanks !!

Comment: @Aindriu I believe others have mentioned it, but just to be clear ALL the other solutions do attempt to cast the object.  They will throw exceptions if the object is not a ``Student``, just like your for loop example.

Answer (score 4):

You should always keep trying to figure out these kinds of beginner issues, but here's the answer to your question:

```
public void ListStudents()
{
    foreach(Student student in studentArrayList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I need to  cast the returned object from the ArrayList to a Student object ... like  Student currentStudent = (Student)studentarraylist[i];

Comment: It's implicitly cast.

Comment: @Aindriu: No you don't. The `foreach` is already doing it for you. `student` is a `Student`.

Comment: @Aindriu You should look in MSDN before you post a question on SO, more often than not you'd find your answer.

Comment: @JoshL. Actually that's not implicit, it's explicit. You are telling it to cast the objects in the array list into `Student`s.

Comment: I did, I couldnt get the foreach loop to work with the   cast the returned object from the ArrayList to a Student object.

Comment: @Aindriu: What do you mean? Your code is "returning" anything for a start and inside the loop your object is already a `Student`.

Comment: @MattBurland Well I looked into it and I'm not sure it's an explicit cast. It's calling "as" so it's more of a check than a cast, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JoshL. It's not an `as`. If you were to take your array list of `Student` and then add, say `new object()` to it, then try to do the `foreach` loop, it would throw an exception because it can't cast `object` to `Student`. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCeuTK) for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (Student student in studentarraylist)
{
    Console.Writeline("Student {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
}
```

It's exactly whats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

> I need to cast the returned object from the ArrayList to a Student object like the above

The entire point of using a foreach loop is so you don't have to cast the object, or more accurately you are doing it in the part where it says

```
foreach (Student student in studentarraylist //here)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var element in studentarraylist){
    var currentStudent = (Student) element;
    Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", currentStudent.FirstName, currentStudent.LastName);
}
```

Comment: So long as the list *only* contains `Student`, you can simplify with `foreach (Student currentStudentent in studentarrayList)` to avoid having to cast

Comment: is " var currentStudent = (Student)element" Casting the student object in the ArrayList to Student object ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This will cast the element to student object.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Student student in studentarraylist)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works only if every object is a student.  It will attempt to cast each element to a student.  This is fine if this isn't a concern to you.

```
foreach(Student currentStudent in studentarraylist)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", currentStudent.FirstName, currentStudent.LastName);
}
```

A better method would be remove the `ArrayList` completely, and instead use a `List<Student>`.

```
var studentsList = new List<Student>();
studentsList.Add(new Student { FirstName = "Aaron", LastName = "Rodgers" });

foreach (var student in studentsList)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
}
```

Also with a list you can use some LINQ if that's your thing.

```
studentsList.ForEach(student => 
   Console.WriteLine("Student {0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName));
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, if all the objects are of type `Student`, then you can just use the `for` loop without a cast, and you should consider using a `List` (or anything other than `ArrayList`) instead.

If for some reason you are storing objects of types other than `Student` in your `studentsArrayList`, then you can get just the `Student` types by doing something like:

```
foreach (var someObject in students)
{
    // Try to cast the object as a Student
    var studentCast = someObject as Student;

    // If it's not null, the cast succeeded
    if (studentCast != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", studentCast.FirstName, studentCast.LastName);
    }
}
```

Or using Linq:

```
foreach (Student student in students.ToArray()
    .Where(s => s.GetType() == typeof (Student)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", student.FirstName, student.LastName);
}
```